VPS as a network storage via Wireguard
I would like to use a cloud-provided VPS as NAS for writing copies of data. Thus I need to integrate it in my local network.
VPS, serving as Wireguard server peer has interface wg0 with internal address 192.0.0.1.
The only client peer has Wireguard interface wg1 with internal address 192.0.0.2. At the same time it has local network address 192.168.1.11. It also has ip forwarding enabled and has iptables rules set as -A FORWARD -i wg1 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enxb82 -j MASQUERADE
Wireguard connection is establishing and working as expected. It is also expected, that I can mount NFS share created on VPS at machines in 192.168.1.0/24 network, but it doesn't work, and pinging VPS from this network doesn't work either.
For testing purposes machine 192.168.1.50 have static route 192.0.0.1 via 192.168.1.11 dev eth0 Ping from this machine receive no replies.
At the same time tcpdump at client peer's interface wg1 gives this output:
19:31:00.785941 IP 192.168.1.50 > 192.0.0.1: ICMP echo request, id 70, seq 3, length 64

Server's public internet interface receives those IMCP requests as UDP datagrams, but they do not get to wg0 interface.
If I add my LAN addresses to AllowedIPs section for wg0 ping runs, but I don't want my LAN to be known to VPS, only vice versa.
I assume that the problem is in masquerading, when peer is not replacing LAN requests to it's Wireguard counterpart, but can't find any similar example in Internet to fix it.


DO NOT use 192.0.0.0/24. It's not RFC1918, and will break things. 2. Do not use masquerading unless you have to. You don't. Do proper routing.


As @vidario state.
Do not use 192.0.0.0/24 for your VPN as it is not RFC1918 address.
It is a special subnet on the Internet that is reserved by IANA.
Your options for ip ranges for your VPN is as follows:



IP range
Available IP addresses




10.0.0.0/8
10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255


172.16.0.0/12
172.16.0.0 - 172.31.255.255


192.168.0.0/16
192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255



You do not need to use the entire range of the available subnet. It is perfectly legal to divide the available range into smaller subnets. :-)
So the best in place substitute in you example would probably by using 10.0.0.0/24 for you VPN, since you just have to replace one number in your VPN configuration.
That is:

Server internal ip would be: 10.0.0.1.
Client ip would be: 10.0.0.2.

However I am a bit confused about your static route.
You only need static routing if you have a setup in the likes of this:

Either the router or PC2 need to have the static route in order to ping the internal ip address of the VPN server.
If you just want to access the NFS share from PC1 then there are no need for static routing, since PC1 is directly attached to the VPN server via VPN.
But that takes only care of one direction of the routing.
In order for the VPN server to communicate with any other host on the 192.168.1.0/24 subnet other than the VPN client, then you need to add a static route on the VPN server, telling that the subnet 192.168.1.24/24 is available through the host 10.0.0.2.
And you also need to enable ip forwarding on the host 192.168.1.11, which may be a little tricky depending on the OS on the machine.
And you need to tell the firewall on PC1 that:

Traffic from 192.168.1.0/24 to 10.0.0.0/24 is allowed
Traffic from 10.0.0.0/24 to 192.168.1.0/24 is allowed

With all those changes then it is possible for all machines on your LAN to ping the VPN IP on the server and vice versa.

Thank you and @vidario for comments about 192: addressing, I have tested installation with 192.168.2.0/24 and it has the same result. For clarification, I want to mount NFS share from wg server on 192.168.1.50 (local machine), where local machine have no wg interface.

Ok. Then you need static routing configured on both router and server as I mentioned in my answer. The router take care of traffic to the server, while the static route on the server take care of traffic to your LAN and thereby ensuring two-way communication.

That's exact what happening, when I add LAN subnet to peer configuration at wg0.conf server side: AllowedIPs = 192.0.0.2/32, 192.168.1.0/24 In this case machines can see each other. But I don't want that WG server know about my LAN. Only about the peer, which serves as NAT for that LAN.

Remember vi said don't use 192.0.0.2/32. The correct IP and mask would be 192.168.2.2/32. As for not knowing your whole LAN, you could reduce the mask 192.68.1.0/24 to 192.168.1.50/32. Same goes for static route rule on server. The router or your secondary PC would at minimum need to have a static route telling 192.168.2.1/32 is available via 192.168.1.11.

Thank you for your replies. The problem was in misconfigured iptables. In configuration that I've mentioned -A FORWARD -i wg1 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enxb82 -j MASQUERADE masquerdaing must be implemented at wg1 interface so that all request from LAN be translated into wireguard addressing. So, after setting POSTUP to iptables -A FORWARD -i wg1 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wg1 -j MASQUERADE 192.168.1.50 host can ping and mount VPS.
